# Issue with converting CHAR to VARCHAR in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, casting, char, varchar

I am observing a very strange behavior. Please consider the following:

```
declare @a char(15)
set @a = 'ABC'
select len(@a), len(convert(varchar, @a)), convert(varchar, @a) + 'D', len(convert(varchar, @a) + 'D')
```

In the produced result set the values 3 and 4 are unexpected:

```
3    3    ABC            D     16
```

Could it be a bug in SQL Server?  Any other explanations?

Comment: In twenty years of working with SQL Server, on average I've seen an actual Microsoft bug that results in unexpected data coming back from a query about once a decade. If you think you're seeing one, it's much more likely that you're just not understanding the correct behaviour.

Comment: If it is not clear, the point of the question is not whether this is a SQL Server bug or not.  The point is that this behavior appears to be somewhat illogical and thus unexpected.  So, instead of general stylistic criticism, a meaningful explanation of the behavior would be welcomed.

Answer (score 3):

The `char` datatype is fixed width and pads with trailing spaces.

So your `char(15)` value is padded out with 12 trailing spaces (replacing spaces with under score for clarity) `ABC____________`

From the documentation for [`LEN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx)...

> Returns the number of characters of the specified string expression,
>   **excluding trailing blanks**.

[`DATALENGTH`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms173486.aspx) does count trailing spaces.

Comment: Or `RTRIM` the columns (after casting to varchar of course) to strip the spaces.

Comment: @DavidG - no need to cast explicitly. `declare @a char(15);set @a = 'ABC';select DATALENGTH(rtrim(@a))` returns `3`. The datatype of the result is `varchar(15)`. But of course assigning back to `char(15)` will just leave the OP where they started.